# How to mark data as demo data in SQL database

Tags: normalization, database-normalization

We haave Accounts, Deals, Contacts, Tasks and some other objects in the database. When a new organisation we want to set up some of these objects as "Demo Data" which they can view/edit and delete as they wish.

We also want to give the user the option to delete all demo data so we need to be able to quickly identify it.

Here are two possible ways of doing this:

1. Have a "IsDemoData" field on all the above objects : This would mean that the field would need to be added if new types of demo data become required. Also, it would increase database size as IsDemoData would be redundant for any record that is not demo data.
2. Have a DemoDataLookup table with TableName and ID. The ID here would not be a strong foreign key but a theoretical foreign key to a record in the table stated by table name.

Which of these is better and is there a better normalised solution.

Answer (score 0):

As a DBA, I think I'd rather see demo data isolated in a schema named "demo".

This is simple with some SQL database management systems, not so simple with others. In PostgreSQL, for example, you can write all your SQL with unqualified names, and put the "demo" schema first in the schema search path. When your clients no longer want the demo data, just drop the demo schema.

Comment: But doesn't that mean when I want to display the list of accounts I have to go: SELECT * FROM Accounts UNION SELECT * FROM Demo.Accounts

(Actually I am using entity framework code first but that's the command in theory).

Comment: Do you intend to mix real data and demo data? That doesn't sound like a good idea to me.